# Is there a way to change tableView cell's height, when the label text in it is modified?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a custom UITableViewCell class and a label in it. I want to autoresize the cell's height when the label text is modified and I've already tried to remove the heightForRowAt data source method and add  'tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 and tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0` 
but it doesn't work. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your tableView like that:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

And make sure your `constraints` are correctly set and your label as `numberOfLines = 0`